# How to Use the Results from FindBugs

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, ant, findbugs

I use the ant command for findbugs and am left with an XML file. Using gedit to open the file, I can tell there there is a bug but I don't know what to make of the error it gives me. Is there a better way that I should be using this file/understanding the results from findbugs? Using netbeans to code in java.

Edit : What do I make of the XML file it gives me? It just says there's a style bug on a certain file with no clarification.

Comment: You can specify the output format for FindBugs, including XML, HTML and emacs. FindBugs has a dedicated GUI. There is an Eclipse Plugin for FindBugs. I am quite sure there a plugins for IntellJ IDEA, emacs, whatever IDE you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FindBugs integration built-in to Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/code-inspect.html#fb).

Here is a nice video tutorial : [New in NetBeans IDE 8.0.1: FindBugs 3.0 for Java 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcdvgkXZXHg)